# cannot create stackbltiz with fullcalendar

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, stackblitz

I want to create a stackblitz with fullcalendar but I got this error code:

```
Error in /turbo_modules/@fullcalendar/core@6.1.7/internal-common.cjs (3:14)
Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-7tmeve?file=App.tsx)